# Automated sitemap in CakePHP

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, sitemap

I'm following [this tutorial](http://mentalramblings.info/posts/view/automatic-sitemap-generation-with-CakePHP-1.2) for creating automated sitemaps in CakePHP. Everything is easy, but I'm not able to output XML. The controller looks like

```
function sitemap ()
{
    Configure::write ('debug', 0);
    $cats = $this->Category->find('all', array('fields' => array('nicename', 'modified')), null, -1);
    $posts = $this->Post->find('all', array('fields' => array('name', 'modified')), null, -1);
    $this->set(compact('cats','posts'));
    $this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');
    $this->viewPath .= '/xml';
    $this->layoutPath = 'xml';
}
```

so it uses the layout app/views/layouts/xml/default.ctp

The problem is that I have no clue what to put in the layout file, and in the tutorial there is no indication. If I put

```
<?php
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'. "\n";
    echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

I obtain a file in the correct format, but as text. If I put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
```

I obtain an XML file (it is displayed differently in Firefox) but completely empty, so the XML parser complains. What is the right way?

Comment: link "this tutorial" is not working. please consider and edit it with correct link. thnks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled upon your question and was sad to see it unanswered. So let's give it a try.

In your controller you already have `$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('xml');` so according to [this comment](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/automatically-generate-dynamic-sitemaps#comment-2867), it should be plenty enough. Did you try leaving out the layout blank?

Also, you should have `var $components = array('RequestHandler');`at some point either in your sitemap controller, or your app_controller.